# called from Blazor client HttpClient.GetJsonAsync returns (with data), but then times out

Tags: c#, blazor

I am making a `Http.JsonAsync<MyType>("api/MyController/Users");` call which returns very quickly but then times out in 5 secs rather than giving me the data.

I have made other such calls that have worked fine, but something weird is going on.

I started from the standard weather service Blazor client template and all worked fine

I kick it off from a button event

```
<button onclick=@load_click>LOAD!</button>

@functions {
private void load_click()
{
    try
    {
        Logger.Log($"about to call PopulateExistingUsers");

        var taskUsers = Http.GetJsonAsync<UsersPageData>("api/ShowerQ/Users");

        Logger.Log($"returned from async requesting users");
        if (!taskUsers.Wait(5000))
        {
            throw new Exception($"timeout!");
        }
        var users = taskUsers.Result;
        Logger.Log($"populated existing users ok.  Users.Count = {users.Users.Count()}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Server side Controller code:

```
[HttpGet("Users")]
public UsersPageData GetUsers()
{

    try
    {
        var users = _repos.GetAllUsers().ToList();
        Log($"returned from GetALlUsers() with {users.Count} users");

        return new UsersPageData() {Users = users};
    }
    finally
    {
        Log($"aft6er returning from method {nameof(GetUsers)}");
    }
}
```

`Logger.Log` just does `Console.Writeline`, which goes to the browser console - very handy!

Expected:
log output to console:
"populated existing users ok.  Users.Count = 3"

ACtual logs:

The output I'm getting is:

```
WASM: 09:31:26.49:about to call PopulateExistingUsers

WASM: 09:31:26.56:returned from async requesting users

WASM: 09:31:31.57:System.Exception: timeout!

WASM:   at ShowerQWeb2.Client.Pages.Index.load_click () [0x00048] in C:\Users\XXXX\Source\repos\ShowerQWeb2\ShowerQWeb2.Client\Pages\Index.razor:62
```

and on server side (which is running on same machine so clocks are in sync apart from a hour)

```
10:31:26.68:returned from GetALlUsers() with 3 users

10:31:26.68:aft6er returning from method GetUsers
```

The chrome network debug shows whats being returned:
response header:

```
Date: Mon, 13 May 2019 09:31:26 GMT
{"users":[{"id":1,"name":"David XX"},{"id":2,"name":"Sumith YY"},{"id":3,"name":"David ZZ"}]}
```

So, it looks like its getting stuck deserializing maybe?

Comment: Oh, I'm using Core 3 Preview 5, VS2019, chrome 73 (same on Edge tho!)

Comment: Also, not that the 5 second timeout is imposed by myself - I have tried longer timeouts

Comment: If you have updates to your question, don't add comments, instead [edit] your question. However, I think the problem is as I describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting stuck in a deadlock because you are abusing async. You shouldn't be calling `.Wait()` and `.Result`, use async code properly.

First make the method `async` and return a `Task`:

```
private async Task load_click()
{
    // snip
}
```

Then `await` your HTTP calls properly:

```
var users = await Http.GetJsonAsync<UsersPageData>("api/ShowerQ/Users");
```

Comment: I was originally doing this, but in an attempt to simplify I removed as much of the async as possible.  I will put it back to its original and try again, and get back

Comment: Mmm, that does seem to be working now.  I also missed off a parameterless constructor on something that was json d/s'ed.

Thankyou.  I need to read up a bit moe on .Wait and .Result.  I had assumed they would simplify things by effectively making it synchronous-ish